# @Page Route for All Pages under a folder

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am just leaning ASP.NET Core Razor Pages and mostly familiar with ASP.NET Web Forms. I have a folder named `Dashboard` with multiple razor pages. I know that at the top of each page I can add the following `@Page "{CONID}"` . My application requires a connection id that I use for my pages to identify the database connection I need to when I query data and this is passed from my login page based on a connection the user selects.

The question is, how can I apply this `@Page "{CONID}"` to all my pages in the `Dashboard` folder or other folders without having to add it at the top of each page?  Is that possible?  I will have many pages and many different folders that all will have this requirement.

[image: Image of problem]

Comment: I have given you a reply, you can try this code , if you have some other problems, please let me know, if not you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Sorry. Been real busy and have not had a chance to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by modifying each route template and not using the Add, which just adds another template to the existing route templates.

```
        services.AddRazorPages(options => {
            var folders = new string[] { "/Dashboard" };
            for (int k = 0; k < folders.Length; k++)
            {
                options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention(folders[k], model =>
                {
                    var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
                    {
                        var selector = model.Selectors[i];
                        selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = 
                        AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template, "{CONID}");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

> how can I apply this @Page "{CONID}" to all my pages in the Dashboard
> folder or other folders without having to add it at the top of each
> page? Is that possible?

Yes, it is possible.

In the `ConfigureServices` of startup.cs file, you can achieve your needs by register  **`AddRazorPagesOptions's Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention`**.

First, put all the folder names in a string array, then loop this array to add **AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates** to each folder's `PageRouteModel.Selectors`
as follow:

```
services
       .AddMvc()
       .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
       {
           var folders = new string[] { "/Dashboard", "/Courses" };//you can add more folders
           for (int k = 0; k < folders.Length; k++)
           {
               options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention(folders[k], model =>
               {
                   var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
                   for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
                   {
                       var selector = model.Selectors[i];
                       model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                       {
                           AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                           {
                               Order = 2,
                               Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(
                                   selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template,
                                   "{CONID?}"),
                           }
                       });
                   }
               });
           }

       });
```

You can also have a look for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-3.1#page-route-action-conventions).

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: This didn't work.  It is adding it to the routes, I want to make it a required template {CONID}, but it adds it to the selectors.  So route /Dashboard works as well as /Dashboard/Index and /Dashboard/Index/SOMECONNECTION.  I only want /Dashboard/Index/SOMECONNECTION to work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  As usual Microsoft Documentation leads you down a rabbit hole of unknowns and you just keep poking at it until something turns up.